# cluetip does not work for first click on live elements after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, cluetip

On live elements after ajax success, below code from cluetip is not working for first click only otherwise it works smoothly.
What will be the issue for first click?

```
  $('a.load-local').live('click', function(event) {
     $('a.load-local').cluetip({
        width: 'auto',
        activation: 'click',
        local:true,
        sticky: true,
        arrows: true,
        positionBy:'bottomTop',
       cursor: 'pointer',
       closePosition: 'top',
       closeText: '<img src="images/close1.jpg" alt="close" width="16" height="16"         
        style="position:absolute; right:5px; top:0px;" />'
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know cluetip, but is it possible the first click is actually initialising cluetip for the clicked element, and then it works normally? (even though you'd be re-intialising it with every click)

A quick look at their demo page http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/ suggests the cluetip method does initialise, not invoke.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `cluetip` is getting initialized everytime you click the anchor - `a.load-local`. In my opinion only the below code is needed, which you can add in `$('document').ready()`

```
 $('a.load-local').cluetip({
        width: 'auto',
        activation: 'click',
        local:true,
        sticky: true,
        arrows: true,
        positionBy:'bottomTop',
       cursor: 'pointer',
       closePosition: 'top',
       closeText: '<img src="images/close1.jpg" alt="close" width="16" height="16"
       style="position:absolute; right:5px; top:0px;" />'
    });
```